# Upload photos on facebook user account while he's offline

Tags: c#, facebook, permissions

I'm developing a server side application with ASP.NET and C# with Facebook C# SDK (http://csharpsdk.org/).

This application gets the user permission publish_stream the first time the user login then the application works on background, without user interaction.

The application will upload a custom image on user photos periodically, and posts them on user wall.
I need to know if it's possible, I mean if it's possible to build an application that upload photos while he is not authenticated for the application.

In my tests, I noticed that it is possible for status with app access token, but with photos I had issues: I receive the following message:

```
A user access token is required to request this resource.
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it is not possible to upload photos without authentication of user, nothing stops you from implementing next flow:

- [authenticate the user](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/login/)
- [extend user's `access_token`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/extending-tokens/)
- store extended `access_token` on your end
- upload photos using stored `access_token`

Answer (score 0):

> I need to know if it's possible, I mean if it's possible to build an
>   application that upload photos while he is not authenticated for the
>   application.

Of course this isn't possible, in order to post the photo, you have to have the permission to do so.

> In my tests, I noticed that it is possible for status with app access
>   token, but with photos I had issues: I receive the following message:
>   A user access token is required to request this resource.

This clearly indicates you need a authentication token to do this.

You should be able to renew/extend token without user interaction if it has expired.

Comment: You will not receive new user's `access_token` without interaction of the user!

Comment: @JuicyScripter - When I said "new" token I was talking more of extending/renewing the token that already existed.  I wrote my answer based on the author already knowing how OAuth worked.